# How to write a program that returns the index position of last occurrence of a given value in an integer array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

For example given an integer array:

{1, 2, 3, 1, 4} and an integer value 1

The method will return 3 as the last index position of the given value. If the array does not contain the given value, then the method should return -1.

My code:

```
public int lastIndexOf(int[] values, int value) {

    for( int i=0; i< values.length ; i ++ )
        if( values[ i ] == value)
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Result what I'm getting:

```js
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :5
Actual   :-1
```

Expected result:

```
 @Test
public void testLastIndexOf() {
    assertEquals(5, main.lastIndexOf(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, 1));
    assertEquals(-1, main.lastIndexOf(new int[]{2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4}, 1));
    assertEquals(0, main.lastIndexOf(new int[1], 0));
    assertEquals(4, main.lastIndexOf(new int[]{0, -1, 1, 8, 8, -1, 6, -2}, 8));
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: especially if it's something as easy to write as this, while you haven't tried anything yourself.

Comment: You need one loop, so if you don't know how yo may learn more Java before trying this, if you know try it

Comment: @Stultuske It's not true that I don't try. I am a beginner in Java and requires some help but comments like yours really demotivate a beginner who don't have a proper source to study. Also I have updated my code in question and the result which I'm getting. Hope to get any help now.

Comment: @azro It's not true that I don't try. I am a beginner in Java and requires some help but comments like yours really demotivate a beginner who don't have a proper source to study. Also I have updated my code in question and the result which I'm getting. Hope to get any help now.

Comment: @user13060550 your logical error is that you start at the first character, you have to start at your last character and work your way back, or you'll get the first index. If you don't show any code, which you initially didn't, we can't see that you tried

Comment: I was saying that because your show NO code (so no effort) now you posted code this changes my mind ;)

Comment: You could have converted your array to list, and use [standard implementation of lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the last index, yoy may read the array in reverse order, from end to start to be able to stop at first match

```
public int lastIndexOf(int[] values, int value) {
    for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (values[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```